# Select all rows where the column value is the "same" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

So I have a table which stores a URL in a column. Due to URL's being parsed and written differently, there are duplicates in the table. How can I select all rows that have the same domain and path of the URL?

I can select duplicates where the URL is an exact match, but that is not what I want.

Examples,

```
# This is a duplicate
https://www.example.com/example1
https://example.com/example1

# Not a duplicate
https://example.com/example2
https://example.com/example3

# This is a duplicate
https://example.com/example2/
https://example.com/example2
```

Comment: So your question can be rephrased as "how can I remove trailing slashes and 'www.' from a string", right?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to delete duplicated rows, using a list of IDs returned from the query I am seeking help with. The table in question has 5 million rows.

Comment: Yes, you already said, that you're able to select duplicates. You don't have to update records to remove certain parts of a string. Selecting in a certain way is enough. So the question can be rephrased like I said, no?

Comment: I am able to select exact duplicates, I expect a query to find URLs that essentially have the same destination although not the same URL will require a replace on it so you could argue that yes, and then select with the replaced string.

Comment: Does pattern matching could resolve it ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? If you're using 8.x then you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` to remove the parts of the URL you want to ignore. Then you can do a self-join to find rows that match on the replaced URLs.

Comment: I am using version 5.7 :)

Comment: please provide some example data and the expected result of these data.

Comment: I mean the title says it all, I want to select all rows from a table where the column value is stored more than once, but only return this row once. For example, if I had these column values: `test1`, `test2`, `test2`, `test2`, `test3` it would return `test2`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the duplicate value using this.

```
DELETE t1 FROM urls t1
INNER JOIN urls t2 
WHERE 
    t1.id != t2.id AND 
    t1.url = TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM REPLACE(t2.url, '://www.', '://'));
```

This is the example url: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=792b0a7870b1abdd91f13cd4c608ab6a

Comment: If so, you can use this `select * FROM urls t1
INNER JOIN urls t2 
WHERE 
    t1.id != t2.id AND 
  t1.create_at >= t2.create_at AND
    t1.url = TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM REPLACE(t2.url, '://www.', '://'));`

Comment: See my comment on the other answer, I don't think a join is what I need for this, there is only one table involved.